# Jmeter. Как собрать в массив и потом использовать данные из json

Tags: jmeter

К примеру ответ вернул
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "IntDocNumber": "20600008976239"
        },
        {
            "IntDocNumber": "20600008982575"
        },
        {
            "IntDocNumber": "20600008982554"
        },
..............................
как мне собрать значения для ключей "IntDocNumber" и далее использовать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) к тому элементу, который возвращает этот ответ
2. Настройте его примерно вот так:

   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor configuration]
3. На выходе вы получите следующие переменные (можно посмотреть при помощи [Debug Sample](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)r и [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener):

   ```
   IntDocNumber_1=20600008976239
   IntDocNumber_2=20600008982575
   IntDocNumber_3=20600008982554
   IntDocNumber_matchNr=3
   ```

   [image: JMeter Variables from JSON Extractor]
4. View Results Tree также позволяет тестить JSON Path выражения при помощи JSON Path Tester, в этом случае не нужно перезапускать тест и добавлять Debug Sampler
   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]
5. Обычно переменные такого вида используют, например, в [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

   [image: JMeter ForEach Controller]

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Есть еще один вопрос: как мне, имея картинку на диска, преобразовать ее в base64 и прикрепить к какой-нить заранее определенной переменной, чтоб отправить на сервер апи-запрос? В идеале, хотелось бы лично с Вами, Дмитрий, услышаться)). У меня очень много вопросов по Jmeter. На проекте щаз пул задач появился для load-testing и прям не знаю к кому и обратиться.

Comment: Функция [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup), ставится в пакете **Custom JMeter Functions** через [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)